# How to check if parameter passed to Lua is of user defined type?

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, ogre

I am implementing scripting for my Ogre3d based application using Lua and I have encountered a problem with checking whether a parameter fed into function is of particular type - Ogre::SceneNode*. Anybody knows how can I do it ?

There are some basic Lua functions doing this for built in types like int or string e.g.

`if(lua_isnumber(L,1))
{...}`

but I do not know how to do it with user defined types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `lua_isuserdata(L, yourParam)` ?

Would be logical.

Comment: Yep, along with `lua_islightuserdata()`

Comment: hmm yes that seems to be right but how can I check whether it is this particular type of data and whether this Ogre::SceneNode exists ?

Comment: @Heandel
Ok, so I got this now:

`Ogre::SceneNode* sceneNode = dynamic_cast<Ogre::SceneNode*>( lua_touserdata(L, 2) );`
but I cannot do that because
error C2681: 'void *' : invalid expression type for dynamic_cast

Comment: @Heandel : What do you mean by that ? I have done something like this now:
`sceneNode = (Ogre::SceneNode*)( lua_touserdata(L, 2) );`
but anyway the 
`lua_islightuserdata(L,2)` or `lua_isuserdata(L,2)`
returns false.

Obviously it can be of another type but it shouldn't.

Comment: @Haendel : I think I will have to implement much more than I thought. the problem is that I want to run in the .lua file function that takes as an argument Ogre::SceneNode* but can I just put `foo(mNode)` where mNode is a variable from c++ class ? I doubt it right now :/ so to do that I will have to write a function that return a user type data. how can I do that ? I have found that there are some problems with `lua_pushuserdata()`.

Comment: hmm... I will try to figure it out but it looks rather complicated:/

Comment: @Haendel : Ok, so I have looked at this example [http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_call](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_call) but I still doubt that it is what I want to achieve, namely: I have this `OgreApp1::getSingleton().mNode` in the c++ and I want to somehow call form lua script file `foo( ... , mNode )` or equivalent.

Comment: hmmm... that might be a bit offtopic but I cannot use `lua_pushuserdata()` function. I don't know why but it is not defined in my lua ( and I have the most recent version.

Comment: I have used now `lua_pushlightuserdata()` and it works. But now I have a problem because I would like to use this returned variable in lua. On this site [http://loadcode.blogspot.com/2007/02/wrapping-c-classes-in-lua.html](http://loadcode.blogspot.com/2007/02/wrapping-c-classes-in-lua.html) there is a good tutorial about this. I will try to check this out later on.

Answer (score 2):

If you arrange for each of your `userdata` of a particular type to share a metatable, then you can use [luaL_checkudata](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_checkudata) to confirm their type. This is typically how a library tags and identifies the data it creates.

Here are some functions that create and check userdata using this technique:

```
static decContext *ldn_check_context (lua_State *L, int index)
{
    decContext *dc = (decContext *)luaL_checkudata (L, index, dn_context_meta);
    if (dc == NULL) luaL_argerror (L, index, "decNumber bad context");
    return dc; /* leaves context on Lua stack */
}

static decContext *ldn_make_context (lua_State *L)
{
    decContext *dc = (decContext *)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(decContext));
    luaL_getmetatable (L, dn_context_meta);
    lua_setmetatable (L, -2); /* set metatable */
    return dc;  /* leaves context on Lua stack */
}
```

The metatable was created with

```
const char *dn_context_meta = "decNumber_CoNTeXT_MeTA";
luaL_newmetatable (L, dn_context_meta);
```